# Custom Alexa Skill Overlapping with Native Echo Alarm

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I have developed a custom alexa skill which  works fine except for the following case :

1. Set an alarm for say 4:30 PM
2. Invoke the Skill at 4:29 and start the conversation with  my custom skill
3. While alexa is conversing with the user , the alarm simultaneously starts playing.

Is there a way to avoid that like pausing my skill while the alarm plays or deferring the alarm

Comment: This is a very interesting question but I believe it belongs on the Amazon Developer forums.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not related to programming.